# How to add a custom button on an item that does not have Stock?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working with `Wordpress` and `WooCommerce`, I need to add a contact button if in my store some product runs out of stock, ie:

> If Stock is 0, show me a contact button.

The following image looks more specific about where I want to insert it:

[image: Show image]

I have found out how to add the button, but it is added to all the products, and I just want the button to appear when I have no stock on any of my products.
Here is the code used:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'boton_subasta');
function boton_subasta(){
     global $product;
    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()){

        echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" onclick="window.location.href=http://http://138.197.9.71/prov-individuales/">contacto</button>';    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a ')' on your `if` statement, that's why condition its not working.

```
if ( ! $product->is_in_stock()){
  echo '<button type="submit" 
class="button alt" onclick="window.location.
href=http://http://138.197.9.71/prov-individuales/">contacto</button>';    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not continue working the code, still does not show me the button where it should.

Answer (score 0):

The action `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` is only called if `$product->is_in_stock()` is true. So, this action will not be called `if $product->is_in_stock() is false`.

In other words, the `Add to Cart` button exists only when `$product->is_in_stock() is true` and will not exists at all if the product is `out of stock` so there is no button to add after.

You may want to do research on the filter `woocommerce_get_stock_html` instead.

However, I don't understand why your button is being displayed. The given code should not show the button. Are you sure the code written in the question is exactly the code you are using?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the interview I'm going to investigate, if it's the same code that I'm showing, what happens is that I was missing a ")" that's why that "Contact" button was displayed but now it does not show it anymore, I'll try with `woocommerce_get_stock_html`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

I have already found a solution thanks to all of you, who have taken me on a good research path, use the following code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'boton_sub_producto_single', 6 );
function boton_sub_producto_single() {
        global $product;
            if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() || ! $product->is_purchasable() ){
                echo '<button type="submit" class="button alt" onclick="window.location.href=http://http://138.197.9.71/prov-individuales/">contacto</button>';
            }
            return $product;            
    }
```

It work for me .